# The minimal complexes and the direct limit

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

In my research I confronted with the following question. I do not have a counterexample, so I ask it  here if anyone knows. I would like a positive answer, however a negative answer seems more likely to me.

A complex $C$ is said to be a *minimal* complex provided every morphism  $\beta:C\rightarrow C$ that is homotopic to id$_C$  is an isomorphism.

**Original question:** Suppose that $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ is a commutative local ring and $\{F_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a direct system of minimal complexes of finite free modules,   each of which a minimal free resolution of $H_0(F_j)$. Then is the direct limit $F=\lim\limits_{\longrightarrow} F_j$ also a minimal complex?

The original question has a couneterexample by the answer below. Later on I modified the question as below.

**Modified Question:** Suppose that $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ is a commutative local ring and $\{F_j\}_{j\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a direct system of minimal complexes of finite free modules,   each of which a minimal free resolution of $H_0(F_j)$, such that $$\lim\limits_{\longrightarrow}H_0(F_j)\neq 0.$$ Then is the direct limit $F=\lim\limits_{\longrightarrow} F_j$ also a minimal complex?

P.S.: The counterexample below definitely can not be changed simply to answer negatively the second modified question, because the main point of the counter-example below is that the resulted direct limit complex is split exact.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a "minimal" counterexample.
Let $R$ be the localization of $k[x]$ at $(x)$, and let $F_j := R \to^x R$ for every $j$, where $\to^x$ denotes multiplication by $x$.   Consider the direct system $$\dots \to F_{j-1} \to^x F_j \to^x F_{j+1}\to \dots$$  Then the colimit is $k(x) \to^x k(x)$  and the $0$ map is homotopic to the identity via $x^{-1}$.

Comment: Nice! That's correct, thanks. In this counterexample the direct limit morphisms induce zero map on the $0$-th homologies. So I change the question a lit bit to exclude this case.

Comment: @Aurora You can modify this example to answer your modified question.

Comment: Yes, you are right again. What I am looking for is to put good restrictions to exclude simple counter-examples. Of course I have examples of such direct limits in mind which preserve the minimal property.

Comment: I'm not sure what a good restriction would be.  One philosophical comment is that this counter-example is related to the fact that minimal iff $R/\mathfrak{m} \otimes_R F$ has zero differential breaks down when Nakayama's lemma fails.   E.g. $k(x) \otimes_R R/(x) = 0$ even though $k(x) \neq 0$.

Comment: Yes, definitely that's the obstruction. Is the new one also easy?

Comment: I think so.  BTW, its considered bad manners to delete your original question after it is answered--people reading it later will get confused. You should indicate the edits/additional questions you make, by saying something like Edit 1, Edit 2, etc.

Comment: If someone reads your counterexample he/she would understand what was the original question. I didn't delete it! I modified it!